# how to add macro defines in Qt .pro file

Tags: c++, qt, macros

I am now using asio alone in my project, which is supposed to be built as a shared library used by others.

But I got the following error:

```
warning Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately.
```

My question is, can I add a macro definition to my `.pro` file to avoid it.

Can someone tell me how to do it, just like add

```
 #define PI 3.1415926
```

to the `.pro` file.

Comment: "MCRO", "MCORO", ...  Do you mean a `macro` or preprocessor define?

Comment: preprocessor define. Just like gcc -dPI=3.1415926.  I am sorry for not asking  my question  clearly. Simon Warta 's answer just works. Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following to your `.pro` file:

```
DEFINES += "PI=\"3.1415926\""
```

In your compile output you will see something like

> g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE **-DPI="3.1415926"** -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../nobackup/qbuffertest -I. -I../nobackup/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/include -I../nobackup/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I../nobackup/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I../nobackup/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../nobackup/qbuffertest/main.cpp

Now you can access the macro in your C++ files:

```
qDebug() << PI;
```